# How do the werewolves follow the vampires in the Twilight series?

Tags: vampire, werewolf, twilight

The werewolves (wolf shifters, if you prefer) somehow go where the vampires go. I believe either Bella, Edward or Jacob mentions that the wolves somehow appeared not long after the vampires moved into Forks (any help finding where this is in the series is appreciated, I'm having difficulties).

Is there any evidence of how the wolves follow the vampires?

Comment: By scent? Wolves tend to have really good noses...

Comment: @FreeMan Maybe? Vampires do have a strong scent . . .

Comment: Wouldn't know, never sniffed a vampire (AFAIK).